# Loop in bash until there are no unique result

Tags: bash, for-loop, amazon-ec2

I created function using bash to retrieve EC2 SnapshotIds and output the list to a text file. I used a for loop:

```
for i in {0..20} ; do
  aws ec2 describe-snapshots \
    --filters Name=description,Values="*TestVolume$i*" \
    --query "reverse(sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime))[0].SnapshotId" \
    >> GetSnapId
done
```

Above outputs the content but the output file has some blanks because of {0..20} where some line are empty. How can I loop to output unique SnapshotIds so that loop stops when all unique SnapshotIds are retrieved? Is using while loop better? What would you suggest?

Comment: Script runs 20 times ({0..20}. Here is sample output:                                                             "snap-lkjjsd813beaca2asdf"
"snap-12346b9301b0eabsd"
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
"snap-1111c2a279f0deder".      I would like the loop to stop when there are no more unique snapshotIds. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi - I've added the whole script above. How can I get the script to print only unique snapshot Ids and not 0 on some of the lines as suggested earlier. Ideally I would like to see latest SnapshotId for a Volume.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution assumes that "aws" returns an appropriate result.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start of Function.."
getLatestSnap() {
    for i in {0..20}
    do
     echo "Retrieving $i SnapshotIds"
     capture=$(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters  Name=description,Values="*TestVolume$i*" --query "reverse(sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime))[0].SnapshotId")
     result=$?
     if ((result == 0))
     then
        echo $capture >> GetSnapId
     fi
    done
}

getLatestSnap
cat GetSnapId
```

The $(...) runs the command in a subshell.  The assignment captures the stdout.
If the command succeeds (the aws command processed a valid volume), the captured output is appended to the file.

Note: I don't have access to the aws command.

Comment: Hi - thank you! Result returns bunch of nulls and only 1 snap-id:      Retrieving 20 SnapshotIds
null
null
"snap-yyy456ss899z54321"
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null

Answer (score 0):

In bash, loops can be used in conjunction with pipes.  That means we can have a fairly simple loop, and post-process the results in a later step.

```
for i in {0..20}
do
  aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters Name=description,Values="*TestVolume$i*" --query "reverse(sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime))[0].SnapshotId"
done | sort | uniq | grep snap > GetSnapId
```

Notice that the `> GetSnapId` has been moved further down, after the post-processing.

The post-processing itself pipes the raw list of snap ids to `sort` and then `uniq`.  These work together collect and then eliminate duplicates.  Next is a grep which will filter out the `null` lines (are those an issue?  It wasn't very clear.)  The result is then sent to the output file.

With this approach I've removed the `echo` to prevent it from being lumped in with the other output coming out of the loop.  If it is essential you could perhaps add it back in but outputting to `stderr`: `1>&2 echo "Retrieving ..."`